# run a python script on raspberry pi turned on

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am working on raspberry pi 3 about 3 months , I had a problem when I started working with it.
I couldn't find an efficient and safe way to run a python script on raspberry when it turns on(without monitor and mouse and keyboard).At the moment I have added "$sudo run myscript.py &" at /etc/profile but sometimes when I turn it on my script doesn't run until I connect monitor and mouse and keyboard to it and run the script with GUI and after that it works fine (again without mouse and keyboard).

I want to know is there any solution that I will be sure my script will run after I turn raspberry pi on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to setup a `service` and user `sudo service <my_service> [start, stop, restart]` to get it working on startup. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351879/how-to-create-a-service-on-ubuntu-upstart) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/profile` is executed when new shell session in being started, so unless you start at least single shell session your script will not be run. Moreover it will be terminated when session stops, and if you start multiple sessions then the script will also be started for each session, which is probably not what you want.

Depending on your init system you would need to create SysVinit or systemd service. Assuming you use systemd based distro (which is currently default for most Linux distributions) you need to do following:

**Step 1:** Place your script in location from which it will be executed by service. For example `/usr/local/bin/` may be good choice.

**Step 2:** Create service file. Assuming you want to name it `myscript.service`, create file at following path `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service` with following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=myscript

[Service]
ExecStart="/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/myscript.py"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 3:** Reload systemd daemon and enable your service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable myscript
```

Now after you restart your system, your service should be automatically started. You can verify that using command `systemctl status myscript`, which returns service status.